# Tools for real-time collaborative editing; based on a server/repository

Tags: git, collaboration, code-sharing

I am writing this post with [floobits](https://floobits.com) in mind. (works a bit like a real-time git)
Floobits lets you host a server/workspace and work off of that, let other people connect by using a single workspace link. The main point is you don't need to share a different "session" link every single time someone else wants to edit and also, the files are saved both locally and on the server, so anyone can edit those files offline and get an option to sync new files to the server etc.
So you see how it is more similar to git than VS Code's Live Share.

The problem is, floobits is no longer being maintained (although no official message but that's what it looks like).

I am looking for collaborative tools that work on either Sublime Text or VS Code which work not by sharing the host's editor, but rather by sharing a whole repository and making edits in real-time, together. (Not like GitLive which just shows different versions of the file and lets you choose what to merge, that's not really editing real-time, that's just enhanced git.)

I hope my question is clear, if any other details are needed please comment!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes GitLive is more about enhancing git, it does offer a real-time editing experience also but I agree it doesn't work like floobits and doesn't exactly fit your use case.

What are you thoughts on https://getsturdy.com/ does that fit your use case more? I think what they are working on is pretty cool.

Full disclosure: I am the founder of GitLive

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
Sturdy is definitely a great tool! However, as far as I can tell from their docs, we can't work on the same file at the same time right? (there are still multiple copies like git, not just one server copy that everyone edits)